# Bom senso (crítica)

Tags: debate

Desculpe, mas vou ser direto.

Sempre que posto algo aqui é sobre algo negativo.
Não gostaria de ficar marcado como um cara negativo.. mas enfim.. Acho que poucos ou ninguém tem coragem de postar isso, pelo menos nunca vi nesse site, então eu vou postar.

Acho muito chato mesmo esse comportamento de alguns usuários desse site.

Você "dedica" um tempinho para compartilhar com respostas úteis e sempre tem um pentelho para negativar ou tentar remover o que vc posta. É frustante, é desrespeitoso.. é ridículo.

Respondi uma questão há alguns minutos e estava navegando lendo outras questões quando vejo a notificação no topo. Clico e vejo alguém lá dizendo que minha resposta é inútil e exigiu que "detalhasse a resposta" e marcou para REMOVER.
Que absurdo! E fazendo num tom como se fosse meu patrão.. kkkkk   que doidera..

Acho um absurdo e desrespeitoso, sabe por quê?
Eu não lembrava de como resolver a questão e fui no google, encontrei resposta e trouxe aqui para o site. Isso me custou uns 2 segundos. Demorei mais para postar do que para encontrar a resposta.

Quer dizer que todo esse "trabalho" que eu tive vai para o lixo?
Dou uma ajuda para um desconhecido, então vem alguém e toca para o lixo o trabalho que forneci de bandeja? Não somente para o autor da questão para para agregar valor ao site também.

Eu nem preciso disso.. não faz diferença alguma para mim, não ganho nada com isso. O máximo que ganhei foi lembrar como resolve. Daqui uns 30 minutos vou esquecer e quando precisar algum dia vou buscar no google de novo.
Mas o fato é, ajudei um terceiro sem querer nada em troca e, ao invés de ter um agradecimento, recebo um chute na cara de um outro que deve ser administrador, cão de guarda ou sei-lá o quê.

Esse site deve estar perdendo muitos usuários por causa dessa política de querer respostas complexas e gigantescas. Nao há necessidade nenhuma disso.

Discutimos isso em outros tópicos e eu compreendo e aceito 100% com a política do Stack.
Quanto a isso não tem problemas. O problema é o comportamento de alguns usuários que ficam chutando outros usuários que colaboram.

Se não curtiu a resposta ou achou que poderia melhorar colocando descrições "titânicas", então ao invés de querer remover o "trabalho" alheio, por que não posta outra resposta do jeito que acha melhor? Aí deixa a comunidade decidir por meio dos votos.
Simples assim. Não precisa ficar aí dando ponta pé feito um ogro.

Já é difícil eu ter um tempo para ficar postando na net.. Tenho filhos, familia, os meus afazeres pessoais. Aí quando tenho um tempinho para compartilhar tenho que aturar essas criancices...

Mais maturidade gurizada... Pois, do que adianta ser bom tecnicamente e não ter maturidade mental?

Desculpe o desabafo e ofensas.. Nada pessoal até por que nem te conheço. (caso esteja lendo)

*Não vou postar o link direto aqui para não aumentar a exposição dos envolvidos.

Esse tempo precioso que gastei aqui postando essa crítica, eu poderia ter usado para ajeitar a resposta, mas nem tenho mais vontade.. Desânimo total mesmo em postar algo.. até parei de ler outras questões..

Comment: Oh a ironia, essa pergunta ser negativada... Sobre [**a resposta em questão**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44647/htaccess-e-redirecionamento-https/44656#44656), ela é curta e direta, mas é perfeitamente aceitável e é claramente uma resposta, não um comentário. Ela resolver o problema da pergunta. Sobre o voto para remover, peço apenas que não tome as ações de um como as ações da comunidade. Eu ficaria impressionado se surgissem outros votos e a pergunta fosse de fato removida. Dito isso, suas contribuições são sempre bem vindas. E, claro, são sempre voluntárias.

Comment: Minha visão pessoal é a seguinte: 1) de fato, a resposta é aceitável (boa até); eu teria acrescentado uma pequena descrição do que aquele comando faz (nada "titânico", uma frase bastaria), mas a ausência disso não invalida sua resposta; 2) o tom do comentário recebido não foi legal: além de seco (apesar do `:)` no final), foi dado da forma imperativa. Não que o usuário em questão tivesse necessariamente a **intenção** de dar uma "ordem", apenas que pela brevidade do comentário ele acabou saindo assim (limitações do texto escrito); 3) Independentemente disso, achei sua resposta desproporcional.

Comment: P.S. "Marcar para remoção" é uma **ferramenta**. E ela não se baseia na opinião de um único indivíduo, mas no consenso entre vários destes *com muita experiência no site*. Eu não hesito em usar essa ferramenta quando julgo apropriado, confiando que se eu estiver errado outros declinarão minha sinalização. E de todo modo, uma coisa é simplesmente remover (o que se aplica a postagens de muito baixa qualidade) e outra é converter em comentário. Caso em que nada se perde, só o formato muda, por questão de organização. E que eu saiba, tem de ser feito por um moderador, não um usuário qualquer.

Comment: Olha vou ser sincero, concordo com muita coisa que você disse, mas tem um porém, existem casos que sim eu acho que algumas respostas devem ser excluídas, por exemplo, outro dia eu li uma resposta totalmente errada (era uma questão sobre CSS), comentei ao usuário que estava errada, lhe passei um link da documentação e aguardei, depois de um dia nada de resposta do usuário, olhei o perfil e vi que ele acessou, então pensei uma resposta "errônea" pode ser removida...

Comment: ... porém outro usuário com poder de moderação rejeitou e ainda me mandou uma resposta dizendo que minha atitude foi errada, do meu ponto de vista achei o maior absurdo. Do meu ponto de vista, se a resposta estiver totalmente errada, devemos comentar e aguardar o usuário editar (geralmente aguardo 24h) ou ele responder, passado o tempo e a questão não for alterada ou não houver justificativa, acredito que devemos deletar sim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não discordo, apesar de achar que 24h é um período muito curto. No final das contas, se uma resposta está errada não há problema em ser removida, mas **caso não seja possível**, uma pontuação negativa já é indicativo suficiente de que ela não está correta.

Comment: Obrigado @Gabe também concordo contigo, porém é possível visualizar pelo perfil do OP da resposta, se ele acessou após o período, se acessou e nem ao menos respondeu ao seu comentário, ao meu ponto de vista já acho o suficiente para solicitar a remoção.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Talvez, mas não dá pra saber sob que condições esse acesso foi feito, ou quanto tempo ele durou. Além disso, manter o olho no log de toda resposta errada é impraticável em larga escala. Por isso eu gosto de simplesmente dar uma janela de tempo mais ampla. Ninguém vai morrer se uma resposta incorreta ficar 2, 3 dias no site. Principalmente se tiver a pontuação negativa. Mas são só diferentes maneiras de atacar o problema, não tem certo/errado.

Comment: @Gabe Obrigado, realmente aumentar o tempo pode ser uma boa pratica. Só não entendi o não tem "certo/errado", você se refere a uma resposta "errada" ou a outra coisa? Por que se for a resposta, eu acho que tem sim respostas totalmente erradas. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ficou esquisito mesmo. Eu tava falando do processo de comentar/esperar/remover a resposta. Não é *errado* esperar 24hs (ou até a pessoa logar), ou *errado* esperar mais tempo. Talvez seja errado excluir sem dar a chance e orientação para melhoria mas, fora isso, são só processos diferentes.

Comment: @Gabe Sim entendi, fui "vitima" (no meu caso foi uma questão) aqui no próprio SOpt de uma atitude destas e por este motivo concordo plenamente com a sua opinião. Obrigado espero que a maioria siga o mesmo caminho que o seu, eu seguirei.

Comment: @Gabe Eu acho que respostas incorretas devem apenas receber votos contra (às vezes, dezenas deles), mas muito raramente serem excluídas. Que é minha interpretação do que está dito na [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: @bfavaretto Como eu disse, não há certo/errado. Tendo o voto definitivo como moderador, eu raramente excluo algo. Mas como usuário "normal" eu provavelmente tomaria mais liberdades. É mais importante garantir que uma boa resposta tenha destaque do que impedir que uma ruim exista.

Comment: So uma observação; no SOen o nivel de exigencia é 100x maior! O nível da resposta para se ganhar os pontinhos aqui, SOpt, é muito mais baixo.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. É bullying o que alguns usuários passam por aqui por causa de outros usuários que se acham deuses da verdade.

Answer (score 14):

Olha, na verdade este não é um problema apenas do StackOverflow em português. É algo que ocorre em todos os sites no StackExchange. Uma das pricipais razões para isso é que o comportamento das filas de análise (se você tiver reputação suficiente as encontrará facilmente) tende a incentivar este tipo de atitude.

Além disso, na internet, as pessoas tendem a ser muito mais frias e desumanas do que na vida real.

Os sites na rede StackExchange prezam pela qualidade do conteúdo, o que é bom, mas muitas vezes o fazem de forma a induzir os usuários a terem comportamentos hostis (na minha opinião), o que é péssimo. A coisa fica pior ainda para quem é principiante no site, que não entende as regras de como as coisas funcionam e por isso tende a acabar sendo mais vítima destes detalhes do sistema.

Quanto aos votos, as pessoas podem votar como bem entenderem com o critério que acharem melhor. O problema é que isso também significa que elas podem votar de forma injusta, o que é muito comum e muito difícil de se combater.

Ah, sim, quase ia esquecendo de mencionar. Dos sites da rede StackExchange que eu conheço, o StackOverflow em português é o mais amigável de todos. Há alguns outros em que os usuários têm uma postura bastante agressiva e crítica, aonde qualquer deslize resulta em uma chuva de downvotes.

Comment: compreendo pois frequento a "rede do stack" há anos..

Comment: +1 pelo último paragrafo.

Comment: Verdade, o stackoverflow inglês é bem cruel. Um dia desses respondi uma pergunta para um cara que estava muito confuso sobre closures e ajax no JavaScript. Um usuário (o que tinha mais votos) deu uma resposta mais complexa, fazendo que com que o autor comentasse que ainda não estava entendendo. Respondi de uma forma mais simples e didática pro cara. Pouco tempo depois o cara com mais pontos já foi colocando uma crítica na minha resposta, dizendo que estava muito simples e não explicava nada. Melhorei e novamente o cara veio com outra crítica. Acabei deixando pra lá...

Comment: @RubensPinheiro Discordo já passei por algo parecido aqui também, no SO em inglês e no português as opiniões dos usuários são muito parecidas, cada um é cada um, existem usuários que que tem sensatez assim como existem os que não entendem e a ferramenta e nem sabem o que é "cavalheirismo". Eu pessoalmente acho o SO-en muito agradável, assim como o SO-pt. O problema é que de vez em quando aparece algum usuário com atitudes arrogantes e faz mal uso da comunidade (independente da comunidade do StackExchange)

Comment: Vitor sobre a chuva de votos negativos eu concordo, realmente parece que isto ocorre em todas comunidades (ao menos as que eu participei), geralmente soa como um "puxa-saquismo".

Comment: No SO-en há muitos mais usuários pois inglês é um idioma internacionalizado. Possui usuários do mundo todo desde Ásia, Oriente Médio, Rússia, Américas, Europa.. enfim, todos. O SO-pt é igual em essência mas não acho que seja mais amigável. Aparentemente é mais amigável porque comparando com o SO-en, possui bem menos usuários de diferentes etnias e culturas. Mas um ponto concordo é, quando um usuário com alta pontuação faz uma crítica, outros, por mero puxa-saquismo, o apóiam, mesmo que esteja errado. É isso que acho meio "perigoso", nocivo.

Answer (score 14):

Tem dois pontos que eu gostaria de comentar.

> Esse site deve estar perdendo muitos usuários por causa dessa política de querer respostas complexas e gigantescas. Nao há necessidade nenhuma disso.

Não existe essa política. A única exigência é que as respostas sejam corretas. Fora isso, vai de cada usuário. Eu, por exemplo, prefiro respostas com explicação. Se vir duas respostas com o mesmo código, uma com explicação e outra sem, provavelmente vou votar só na que tem explicação. Mas não precisa ser nenhuma tese. Inclusive, concisão pra mim é uma qualidade.

> Se não curtiu a resposta ou achou que poderia melhorar colocando descrições "titânicas", então ao invés de querer remover o "trabalho" alheio, por que não posta outra resposta do jeito que acha melhor? Aí deixa a comunidade decidir por meio dos votos. Simples assim. Não precisa ficar aí dando ponta pé feito um ogro.

Bom, deixar "a comunidade decidir por meio dos votos" inclui os votos para excluir e os votos contra. Eu não concordo com o voto para excluir nessa sua resposta específica, mas o usuário que votou entendeu que sua resposta não era uma resposta. O site dá essa ferramenta a parte dos usuários mas também exige que três usuários concordem com a avaliação para de fato excluir a resposta (ou até 6 usuários, se for pela fila de análise e dependendo da reputação deles). Faz parte do mecanismo de garantia de qualidade. Claro que existem erros, mas neste caso *somente um* usuário votou pela exclusão e mais ninguém. O sistema funcionou e sua resposta continuou lá, e foi até votada.

Não sei se está claro pra você tudo o que aconteceu com a sua resposta. O sistema sinalizou a resposta automaticamente porque ela era curta (boa parte das respostas curtas são "obrigado" ou "também tenho esse problema"). Isso a levou para uma fila de análise. Dois usuários viram, [um votou para excluir e outro achou que a resposta estava bem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22804). O fato de terem discordado disparou outra sinalização automática. Ou seja, o sistema chamou a atenção dos moderadores para a resposta duas vezes. E nas duas eu olhei e dispensei as sinalizações.

Por fim, o comentário do outro usuário não foi tão agressivo assim. Tudo bem, entendo que você não tenha gostado do comentário nem do voto, mas sua reação parece um pouco desproporcional. Nesses casos, vale mais a pena não dar bola e seguir em frente.